# Streaming log file data over http by using unix command. Combination of tail and curl

Tags: linux, curl, streaming, monitoring, tail

I need to follow a log file on linux machine and stream the updates of log file  over http port to a remote machine. I have written a command with the combination of "tail" and "curl". 
To test it initially, i used "tail -n", it works well and posts data successfully to remote machine. Below is the command.

*$tail -n 200 /path/to/logfile/file1.log | curl --data-binary @- http://remotemachineIP:9000*

Now, When i try to run the same command with "tail -f", it's not posting any data over http even though the log file is updated multiple times. Below is the command

*$tail -f --follow=name /path/to/logfile/file1.log | curl --data-binary @- http://remotemachineIP:9000*

As per my understanding, "tail -f" is *not* conveying my "curl" command that "input feed is complete over stdin(@-)". Any help on how to rectify this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`curl` will make a single HTTP POST request with the piped data. What you want to do instead is to continuously send the data.

Assuming that by "HTTP port" you actually meant TCP there is a way using `netcat`:

**Remote**

`nc -l 9000`

**Local**

`tailf /path/to/log/file | nc remote_ip 9000`